# Bidirectional reference to parent package in Java

Tags: java, java-package, javaimports

I'm trying to setup a java project with following structure:

```
[Project]
 -parent_class
 -Package
    -child_class
```

Importing and refrencing the *child_class* in the *parent_class* is no problem so far. The reference from *parent_class* to *child_class* seems to be difficult to implement.

Is there any way to access the *parent_class* from the *child_class* without packaging and importing the class via filepath (i.e. like you would add and import a 3rd party libary) ?

parent_class:

```
import Package.child_class;

public class parent_class
{
    private child_class cl;
    
    public parent_class(){
        this.cl = new child_class(this);
    }
    
}
```

child_class:

```
package Package;

public class child_class
{
    private parent_class pc;
    
    public child_class(parent_class p_pc){
        this.pc = p_pc;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: The import of the parent_class in the child_class

Comment: Yes, it does...